# CSharpScript - Could not load System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms

Tags: c#

I'm working on website .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I want use CSharpScript library.
I installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 4.3.0 and I created method in my controller :

```
// GET: Test
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var obj = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("new{x=1}");
    return View();
}
```

But when I call this method, I have this error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : 'Impossible de charger le fichier ou
> l'assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.3.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses
> dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.'
>
> Internal Exception : FileNotFoundException : Impossible de charger le
> fichier ou l'assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou
> une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

Nuget package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms version 4.3.1 is referenced on my project, and in my web.config I have :

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Have you an idee for help me please ? Many thanks !

Charly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted dependentAssembly block in web.config to resolve my problem.